# I am not able to a build a cordova app for android platform on my mac using cordova CLI

Tags: cordova

Here is the basic information about what technologies i am using,
Mac osx yosemite on my macbook pro,
iterm as command line tool
cordova 5.4.1

now let me explain my issue,
 initially i had old cordova version with android sdk around 19 or 20 installed on my mac and i was able to build both android and ios build for default cordova app.

After that i wanted to try with ionic framework and for that i don't know why but i had to upgrade my npm, cordova etc... and i used below link steps for that
http://www.johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/

now after that upgrade i was able to install ionic CLI and able to install default ionic apps but now when i tried to build android app it gives me below error stack trace, i will list the error log at last.

I tried to install latest android sdk version 24.0.1 and still the error is same.
So even after having all required latest sdk versions still it gives me error that i am not having proper sdk build tool as per error log,

So here is error log,
when i run,
cordova build android

```
Running command: /Users/myusername/Desktop/projects/demo8/platforms/android/cordova/build
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /Users/myusername/Desktop/projects/demo8/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/myusername/Desktop/projects/demo8/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/myusername/Desktop/projects/demo8/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.235 secs

/Users/myusername/Desktop/projects/demo8/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/myusername/Desktop/projects/demo8/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/myusername/Desktop/projects/demo8/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/myusername/Desktop/projects/demo8/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/myusername/Desktop/projects/demo8/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I have properly set my path and you can see them belo,

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.6/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/myusername/android-sdk-macosx/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/myusername/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/npm-global/bin:$PATH
alias mphp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.6/bin'
alias serve='php artisan serve'
alias art='php artisan'
source ~/.bashrc
```

So, is there any help so that i can build android app,

Thanks

Comment: I wanna try to debug the gradle file based on this link so that i can know which sdk version is return,
[https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/cordova.gradle]

Answer (score 1):

Did you redact the /Users/myusername part of the path, or forget to make it your actual username?

You can do something like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: As you can see below,
as per my bash_profile file i have mentioned proper path for both tools and platform-tools

export PATH=/Users/myusername/android-sdk-macosx/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/myusername/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:$PATH

Please note that before upgrading based on johnpapa installing npm without sudo, i had everything running smoothly.

So, i have all latest sdk installed and PATH set properly using my pc username but still its not taking sdk and give that error.

Comment: I just marked that in my error stack trace above, in second line it takes `ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk`
where as my android-sdk is in `"/Users/myusername/android-sdk-macosx"`
so now the qusetion is why its taking this path and from where it is set or i can change so that it takes proper sdk path and i guess that should be the soultion for my problem.

Comment: Yes, looks like you need to see what is being set in getAndroidSdkDir() in the Gradle file if the one you linked is what you are using. Perhaps change it to do some logging or throw exception messages to see what it is using.

Answer (score 1):

And finally i got the answer and is as below,
As per my update of npm and node using http://johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/ i had added .bashrc source in my bash_profile and that bashrc file has wrong ANDROID_HOME path which I change and all working fine now.

Thanks guy who responded to this question.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to show this is solved :)